# Is Polar Decomposition Unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-analysis

For an arbitrary complex matrix $A$, it is known that $A$ has either a decomposition $P U$ or $V Q$, where $P = (A A^{*})^{1 / 2}$, $Q = (A^{*} A)^{1 / 2}$, and $U, V$ are isometry. Question: Is it possible for a matrix $A$ to have a decomposition $R W$ or $W R$ (where $R$ and $W$ are positive semidefinite and isometry factors, respectively) such that $R \neq P, Q$?

Comment: $P$ is unique since it is given by an explicit formula involving $A$. For the isometry part $U$, though, consider $A=0$ or in general a matrix not having full rank.

Comment: No. If $A=PU$, then $AA^\ast=(PU)(PU)^\ast=PP^\ast=P^2$ and hence $P$ is necessarily equal to $(AA^\ast)^{1/2}$. The $U$ is not unique, however. E.g. $0=0U$ for every unitary matrix $U$.

Comment: @SangchulLee is it not always 0? Like when $A = P U$, then $0 = A U^{*} = P$.

Comment: @Shuichi Indeed I misread the question. Sorry for the confusion! The new comment should be more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that  $A=VQ=UP$, where $P,Q$ are positive and $U,V$ are isometries.
Then
$$
A^*A=PU^*UP=P^2.
$$
So $P=(A^*A)^{1/2}$. The analog computation for $Q$ then shows that $Q=P$.

There is no uniqueness for the isometry though, without further requirements. For instance let
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
gives you two decompositions with different isometries.

It is common, to get uniqueness, to require instead that $U$ be a *partial isometry* with initial space the range of $A^*$ and final range the range of $A$. This can be stated as $U^*U=[A^*]$, $UU^*=[A]$, where the square brackets denote the range projection.